# How to use a for loop in Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy for a project, in this project I am extracting the information from the xml.

In the xml document the format where I would like to implement the for loop:

```
<relatedPersonsList>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>
        <relatedPersonName>
            <firstName>Mark</firstName>
            <middleName>E.</middleName>
            <lastName>Lucas</lastName>
        </relatedPersonName>
        <relatedPersonAddress>
            <street1>1 IMATION WAY</street1>
            <city>OAKDALE</city>
            <stateOrCountry>MN</stateOrCountry>
            <stateOrCountryDescription>MINNESOTA</stateOrCountryDescription>
            <zipCode>55128</zipCode>
        </relatedPersonAddress>
        <relatedPersonRelationshipList>
            <relationship>Executive Officer</relationship>
            <relationship>Director</relationship>
        </relatedPersonRelationshipList>
        <relationshipClarification/>
    </relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
    <relatedPersonInfo>...</relatedPersonInfo>
</relatedPersonsList>
```

As you can see in the `<relatedPersonsList>`, you can have multiple `<relatedPersonInfo>`, and when I try to make a for loop, I still only get the information of the first person.

This is my actual code:

```
    for person in xxs.select('./relatedPersonsList/relatedPersonInfo'):
        item = Myform() #even if get rid of it I get the same result

        item["firstName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/firstName/text()').extract()[0]
        item["middleName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/middleName/text()')
        if item["middleName"]:
            item["middleName"] = item["middleName"].extract()[0]
        else:
            item["middleName"] = "NA"
```

here is the code that I used on my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector

from scrapy.http import Request
import urlparse
from formds.items import SecformD

class SecDform(CrawlSpider):
    name = "DFORM"

    allowed_domain = ["http://www..gov"]
    start_urls = [
        ""
    ]

    rules = (

        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=["/html/body/div/table/tr/td[3]/a[2]"]),
            callback='parse_formd',
            #follow= True no need of follow thing
        ),
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/div/center[1]/a[contains(., "[NEXT]")]')),
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_formd(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tr[3]/td[3]/a/@href').extract()
        for site in sites:
            yield Request(url=urlparse.urljoin(response.url, site), callback=self.parse_xml_document)

    def parse_xml_document(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = SecformD()
        item["stateOrCountryDescription"] = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerAddress/stateOrCountryDescription/text()').extract()[0]
        item["zipCode"] = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerAddress/zipCode/text()').extract()[0]
        item["issuerPhoneNumber"] = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerPhoneNumber/text()').extract()[0]
        for person in xxs.select('./relatedPersonsList//relatedPersonInfo'):
            #item = SecDform()

            item["firstName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/firstName/text()').extract()[0]
            item["middleName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/middleName/text()')
            if item["middleName"]:
                item["middleName"] = item["middleName"].extract()[0]
            else:
                item["middleName"] = "NA"
        return item
```

I extract the information to a .json file using this command:
scrapy crawl DFORM -o tes4.json -t json

Comment: Try `.//relatedPersonInfo` xpath. Also could you show the whole spider code?

Comment: _"I still only get the information of the first person."_ How do you know what information you got? Are you printing the contents of `item` somewhere? If so, please provide the code where you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def parse_xml_document(self, response):

    xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)

    items = []

    # common field values
    stateOrCountryDescription = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerAddress/stateOrCountryDescription/text()').extract()[0]
    zipCode = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerAddress/zipCode/text()').extract()[0]
    issuerPhoneNumber = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/issuerPhoneNumber/text()').extract()[0]

    for person in xxs.select('./relatedPersonsList//relatedPersonInfo'):

        # instantiate one item per loop iteration
        item = SecformD()

        # save common parameters
        item["stateOrCountryDescription"] = stateOrCountryDescription
        item["zipCode"] = zipCode
        item["issuerPhoneNumber"] = issuerPhoneNumber

        item["firstName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/firstName/text()').extract()[0]
        item["middleName"] = person.select('./relatedPersonName/middleName/text()')
        if item["middleName"]:
            item["middleName"] = item["middleName"].extract()[0]
        else:
            item["middleName"] = "NA"

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Comment: hi paul, thank for your help but unfortunatly after making all the change I still have the same result. (the first person information)

Comment: @Tony, when I run the code I posted with scrapy shell, I get 8 person information. Please post your exact spider code to something like gist.github.com so we can look into it

Comment: you are definitly right Paul, I am sorry, my error came from: stateOrCountryDescription I was still using the old item["stateOrCountryDescription"]... Thank you!!